# Align Text Links Beside Image Links

Tags: html, css

I have these codes:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="parent">
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="image.png">TEXT</a>
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="image.png">TEXT</a>
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="image.png">TEXT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it's giving me this:

[image: Output]

I want to move the text to the right of the image.
Is there anyway I can make it happen without removing the `img-reponsive` class?

I want it to be like:

[image: Output]

Comment: @user3284463 I've edited my codes. The text should be outside of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent > a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="parent">
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">TEXT</a>
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">TEXT</a>
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">TEXT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `pull-left` to the images will work for you:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="parent">
    <a href="link.html" class="pull-left"><img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="//placehold.it/50?text=FB"> FB</a>
    <a href="link.html" class="pull-left"><img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="//placehold.it/50?text=TW"> TW</a>
    <a href="link.html" class="pull-left"><img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="//placehold.it/50?text=IN"> IN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, just give another class and set the `display` to `inline-block`. Because, all the `.image-responsive` does is setting `max-width` and `height` with `display: block;`.

```css
.img-responsive.inline-responsive {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="parent">
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive inline-responsive" src="//placehold.it/50?text=FB"> FB</a>
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive inline-responsive" src="//placehold.it/50?text=TW"> TW</a>
    <a href="link.html"><img class="img-responsive inline-responsive" src="//placehold.it/50?text=IN"> IN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** As I said before, the `img-responsive` adds `block` level display to the `<img />` so it is not possible to have both `img-responsive` as well as having the image's display `inline`... `:(`

Comment: I've edited the codes. There should be text after the image. I am trying bring the text to the right of the image.

Comment: @Jayden I have also updated my solution. Check? I would go with the second option.

Comment: I've tried the codes. It does solve the issue, but is there anyway I can do to not inline the image? I've edited my question with the result I wanted, please take a look.

Comment: @Jayden You want inline as well as block level display? That's crazy thing boss!

Comment: The `img-responsive` class will make it full width! You gotta deal with that! `;)`

Comment: @Jayden No no.. I am not being impolite. LoL. I was just telling you that info that it is **not** possible. It is a *mistake* of Bootstrap?

Comment: I've deleted the comment. It's okay bro. Sorry for misunderstanding your intention.

Comment: @Jayden The second code is the best way I could help you. Wanna take it as an answer? Check and lemme know. Coz you **cannot** have both `inline-block` and `block` applied to an element. You need `inline` or `inline-block`, which makes it obviously unresponsive.

Comment: Okay. Maybe you want to add in a note below saying it's impossible to get the result I wanted? That will makes it easier for users to understand.

Comment: @Jayden LoL fine. `:)`